# Failed to add the foreign key constraint in the plays_for table

Tags: mysql, database

Error : Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'plays_for_ibfk_1' in the referenced table player

my code for the two tables

```sql
create table if not exists plays_for (
    f_name varchar(25) not null ,
    position varchar(30) not null,
    nationality varchar(30) not null,
    club_name varchar(25) not null ,
    season_ending_year year ,
    primary key (season_ending_year, f_name, position,nationality) ,
    foreign key (f_name,position,nationality)references player 
    (f_name,position,nationality),
    
    foreign key (club_name) references club(name)

);


CREATE TABLE if not exists player ( #1
    f_name varchar(25) not null,
    l_name varchar(25) ,
    m_name varchar(25) ,
    date_of_birth DATE not null,
    position varchar(30) not null , #some players donot have a specific position
    nationality varchar(30) not null ,
    height float(23) not null ,
    width float (23) not null,
    primary key (f_name,position,date_of_birth)
);
```

Comment: The table creates are out of order. Create the `player` table first (so that it can be referenced by the foreign key) and then create the `plays_for` table. I'm assuming that table `club` already exists? ... or the foreign key to `club` will have an error too.

Comment: Avoid `if not exists`. It's error prone and can lead to errors difficult to debug.

Comment: Both suggestions did not work out, as I ran the query for the player table before plays_for table

Comment: `foreign key (f_name,position,nationality)references player (f_name,position,nationality)` Why are you trying to create a foreign that contains different columns than the Primary Key? That's likely the issue....